# Extract jsonb in Postgresql - dictionary and array structure in same jsonb field

Tags: arrays, postgresql, dictionary, jsonb

I am using postgresql and I have this table on dataset, that some columns are jsonb.

```
SELECT 
external_id as cod,
title as name,
objectives
FROM table
```

So, the result for "objectives" column is like that:

```
{"blocks":
    [
        {"key":"dek2k",
        "text":"Objetivo Geral",
        "type":"unstyled",
        "depth":0,
        "inlineStyleRanges":
            [
            {"offset":0,"length":14,"style":"fontsize-12pt"},
            {"offset":0,"length":14,"style":"fontfamily-Arial"},
            {"offset":0,"length":14,"style":"fontsize-14"}
            ],
        "entityRanges":[],
        "data":{"text-align":"start"}},
        {"key":"ct1vn",
        "text":"Conhecer e aplicar ferramentas para análise da mídias em sua respectiva relação com a cognição e o design,",
        "type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":
            [
            {"offset":0,"length":216,"style":"color-rgb(0,0,0)"},
            {"offset":0,"length":216,"style":"fontsize-12pt"},
            {"offset":0,"length":216,"style":"fontfamily-Arial"},
            {"offset":0,"length":216,"style":"fontsize-14"}
            ],
        "entityRanges":[],
        "data":{}},
        {"key":"8jshq",
        "text":"","type":"unstyled","depth":0,
        "inlineStyleRanges":[],
        "entityRanges":[],"data":{}},
        {"key":"avq4h",
        "text":"tendo como ênfase os estudos das materialidades dos meios de comunicaçõe e seus aspectos sensoriais.",
        "type":"unstyled",
        "depth":0,
        "inlineStyleRanges":
            [
            {"offset":0,"length":23,"style":"color-rgb(0,0,0)"},
            {"offset":0,"length":23,"style":"fontsize-12pt"},
            {"offset":0,"length":23,"style":"fontfamily-Arial"},
            {"offset":0,"length":23,"style":"fontsize-14"}
            ],
        "entityRanges":[],
        "data":{}}
    ],
"entityMap":{}
}
```

I want to get in result only what is in "text". Sometimes it has just one "text" value, sometimes it has up to 15 or more.

What i need is a result like this for all rows in table:

```
 cod      |      name      | objectives
----------+-----------------+----------
 1        | A              | Objetivo Geral Conhecer e aplicar ferramentas para análise da mídias em sua respectiva relação com a cognição e o design, tendo como ênfase os estudos das materialidades dos meios de comunicaçõe e seus aspectos sensoriais.
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The json functions with `string_agg()` achieve what you want.

Using `WITH ORDINALITY` guarantees correct ordering of the `text` elements.

```
SELECT t.external_id as cod,
       t.title as name,
       string_agg(a.block->>'text', ' ' ORDER BY rn) as objectives
  FROM "table" t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.objectives->'blocks')
                           WITH ORDINALITY as a(block, rn)
 GROUP BY t.external_id, t.title;
```

Comment: I get this error: 
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text -> unknown
LINE 5: ...OSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.objectives->'blocks'...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Can you please show your table definition in your original question?  What is the datatype of the `objectives` column?

Comment: Oh sorry, objectives is a text column with jsonb forma
```
tcreate_table "table", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string "title", null: false
   t.text "objectives"
   t.bigint "institution_id", null: false
   t.integer "code"
   t.jsonb "external_data", default: {}
   t.string "external_id"
   t.jsonb "extra_fields", default: []
   t.bigint "template_id"
```

Comment: @FabíolaMagossi Does this mean you should be using `t."external data"` instead of `t.objectives`?  I have a working DB-Fiddle here:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tJUTm5HXF4jpEVR5qbegZK/0  Please comment if you still have trouble.

Comment: no, the external data have other information that i have trouble to deal with it as well... The one i pasted here is from objectives. Its a text field but it looks like a jsonb

Comment: Try this, then:  `jsonb_array_elements((t.objectives::jsonb)->'blocks')`  Hopefully all of your `objectives` values are valid json.

Comment: i get this error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "Revisão" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: Revisão...

Comment: i think maybe use unnest?

Comment: I am sorry, but that probably means that you have invalid json in your `objectives` column.  You will not be able to use any json functions without fixing your data.  `unnest` works only on `array` types.